# Jenkins integration testing on multiple operating systems

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, jenkins, integration-testing

Currently we use Jenkins on our build server to automate Maven builds of a number of API's and applications. Jenkins is running on a windows machine, but our code is designed to be platform independent. Like most projects, we have platform specific natives which we bundle with our applications which get deployed as they are needed, within the context of the environment the applications are running on. We would like to be able to set up Jenkins so that we can, at the very least, run unit tests across multiple operating systems without having to maintain independent copies of the Jenkins build server for each of the operating systems. It would be great if one instance of Jenkins (the windows one) could communicate remotely to push settings like SVN repo locations, possibly share/merge statistics for code coverage analysis, and configurations for plugins. I dont know a whole lot about Jenkins and am just testing the waters. I found SSH access, and the jenkins CLI which could probably be used to accomplish some of this, but I wonder if there are better ways of accomplishing this. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into setting up multiple [slaves](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) on the appropriate operating systems.
You can build a build pipeline that has jobs that run on slaves in different OSs by restricting those jobs to only run on slaves of the appropriate OS.

Comment: Thank you thekbb. I will look into this tonight and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a plugin like the [vSphere Cloud Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/vSphere+Cloud+Plugin) and use it to spin up new virtual machines on demand. This is more useful in cases where you need node isolation for running functional tests. It also gives you the ability to revert to a known good state by rolling back to a snapshot once a job completes.

In cases where a container would be sufficient, the [Docker Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) works similarly in allowing you to spin up instances on demand.

I have an outstanding question on easily merging test coverage between jobs: [Jenkins Merge Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983103/merging-test-coverage-and-test-results-from-multiple-jenkins-jobs).